# Python и STM32 -- ошибка COM порта

Tags: python-3.x, stm32, port, pyserial

Всем привет. Хочу наладить связь между десктопом и stm32, однако есть некоторые проблемы.
Создаю объект port и выскакивает ошибка

> SerialException: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: OSError(22, 'Параметр задан неверно.', None, 87)

Код создания port

```
import serial
port = serial.Serial()

port.port = "COM16"
port.baudrate = 115200
port.open()
```

Ошибка выскакивает port.open()->self._reconfigure_port(). Платформа windows 10.
Параметры выставил из диспетчера устройств.
При этом у меня получается общаться с STM32 через Tera Term и/или PuTTY

Вот полный скрин ошибки, если кому надо:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду рад любой помощи! Спасибо!

Comment: А порт точно 16-й? А пробовали rate поменьше поставить?

Comment: Да, 16. В диспетчере устройств написано и list_ports.comports() показывает 16. Rate в диспетчере устройств выставлен 115200, однако пробовал менять и в программе, и в диспетчере устройств. Все равно эта ошибка

Comment: [Пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719207/5328783) что это проблема устаревшего драйвера. Можно еще попробовать указать порт по типу `\\.\COM16`

Answer (score 1):

UPD 1:
Зашел я в исходный код Pyserial. В файле serialwin32.py в классе Serial есть функция open(). Эта функция вызывает другую функцию self._reconfigure_port(). Если пролистать последнюю функцию до конца, то можно увидеть строчки

```
if not win32.SetCommState(self._port_handle, ctypes.byref(comDCB)):
             raise SerialException(
            'Cannot configure port, something went wrong. '
            'Original message: {!r}'.format(ctypes.WinError()))
```

Почитав обсуждение на одной ветке github https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/issues/258, я попробовал закомментировать строчки, которые вызывают саму ошибку, а именно

```
if not win32.SetCommState(self._port_handle, ctypes.byref(comDCB)):
            #raise SerialException(
            #'Cannot configure port, something went wrong. '
            #'Original message: {!r}'.format(ctypes.WinError()))
        pass
```

После этого мой порт открылся успешно и я смог отправить команду на свой МК (Визуально загораются светодиоды). Причину этой ошибки можно прочитать в обсуждении (ссылку на github прикрепил выше). Пока работает и никаких других ошибок не выбивает. Если что-то всплывет, то я отпишу.

Comment: Толково. Ну, иногда только так и можно проблему решить - поменяв что-то в самой библиотеке.